# GWT RequestFactory Error when firing request : org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, gwt, maven, requestfactory

I have a maven+spring+gwt project in which i want to use request factory. I just can't figure out why I get this exception.

Request factory:

```
   public interface StarRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {

@Service(value = RaduService.class, locator = GWTServiceLocator.class)
public interface RaduRequestContext extends RequestContext {
       Request<Void> save( );
    }

RaduRequestContext raduRequestcontext();
}
```

Service :

```
public class RaduService {

  public void save(){
    System.out.println("You have saved.");
  }

}
```

Locator :

```
public class GWTServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator,
    ApplicationContextAware {
  private ApplicationContext context;

  @Override
  public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    return context.getBean(clazz);
  }

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
        throws BeansException {
    this.context = context;
  }

}
```

In my entrypoint class i make the request :

```
requestFactory.raduRequestcontext().save().fire(new Receiver<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void response) {
            System.out.println("Success");

        }
    });
```

On this request i get the following error :

[ERROR] Iul 25, 2012 3:35:36 PM com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost
[ERROR] SEVERE: Unexpected error
[ERROR] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.base.star.shared.services.StarRequestFactory$RaduRequestContext] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:269)
[ERROR]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
[ERROR]     at com.base.star.server.integration.GWTServiceLocator.getInstance(GWTServiceLocator.java:25)
[ERROR]     at com.base.star.server.integration.GWTServiceLayerDecorator.createServiceInstance(GWTServiceLayerDecorator.java:43)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.createServiceInstance(ServiceLayerCache.java:117)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.processInvocationMessages(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:451)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:225)
[ERROR]     at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:127)
..........................................................

Does anyone know what is this about ?

I can post the pom if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an Spring error:

Did you annotate your `RaduService` class with `@Service` or define it in your ApplicationContext.xml file as a bean?

Comment: I have defined it in ApplicationContext.xml as :                   <bean id="RaduService" class="com.base.star.server.services.RaduService">
</bean>

Comment: debug your service cod and put a breakpoint in ``public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz)`` of your ``GWTServiceLocator`` and check what it tries to instantiate.

Comment: It tries to instantiate : interface com.base.star.shared.services.StarRequestFactory$RaduRequestContext. Is this ok ?

Comment: No it's not. It should instantiate your ``RaduService.class``.
Check if somewhere in your code you have ``@Service(value = RaduRequestContext.class, locator = GWTServiceLocator.class)`` instead of ``@Service(value = RaduService.class, locator = GWTServiceLocator.class)``

Comment: I've checked. The only service annotation I have is for RaduRequestContext and it is :                            @Service(value = RaduService.class, locator = GWTServiceLocator.class)

Comment: Ok I don't think it will change anything but you can try to move the inner interface definition for your RaduRequestContext out into a separate java file. And also clean the project and re-run the annotation processor/validation tool.

Comment: I have already tried that but it didn't changed anything. I have run maven clean and then re-run, and i get the same error. I can't figure it out.. Do you want me to post the .pom file ? can it be from some bad dependencies ?

Comment: I figured it out. I had a ServiceLayorDecorator class that was calling the ServiceLocator with wrong parameters. Thanks for the help.